# I have a problem locating my java file in vscode

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I use Ubuntu as an operation system and I have a problem in visual studio code, I would really use the help in configuring `java.configuration.runtimes`

[image: screenshot of my vscode]

Comment: run `which java`, and use the directory _containing_ the bin directory.

Comment: i got this directory : /usr/bin/java and i have tried it, i still get the error

Comment: I think that's just a link file. try `whereis java`. You'll get a list where one might be something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`, in which case you'd use `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --display java` for your OS or portable `readlink -f "$(which java)" | sed 's#/bin.*##'`